# Run cron job at 12 am in every time zone

Tags: php, date, datetime, cron, timezone

So I think there is around 30 minutes between each time zone. I want to run my script `cron.php` for at 12 am (midnight) for every time zone. How can I do this?

I was looking at this code:

```
TZ=UTC
* 7 * * * root date | mail root
TZ=CEST
* 7 * * * root date | mail root
TZ=PCT
* 7 * * * root date | mail root
```

Does this work?

What does any of the code mean?

Any better solution?

Comment: *"there's around 30 minutes between each timezone"* - Well, not exactly: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations - most have 1 hour difference, but there are some with 30 minutes of difference, and others with 45 minutes. And who knows if another different one can be created in the future...

Comment: Have it run every minute, and have `cron.php` step through each timezone and see if it's 00:00 there.

Answer (score 2):

Most time zones are 1 hour apart, with a couple of exceptions. 
The above code will run at 7 AM in each of the time zones listed.

It might be better to have a script that runs every hour and just kick that off once in your own time zone